# Matching non-numbers after a few characters with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regexes and I'm validating a form. I want to use `String.prototype.match` to filter out into an array responses which are incorrect. The input should match this form:

```
"foo-1234567"
```

where each identifier always starts with `foo-` and then has 7 digits. If there's more than one identifier, the input takes this form:

```
"foo-1234567\nfoo-7654321\nfoo-1324536"`
```

where identifiers are separated by linefeeds.

I want match to give me each identifier which has `foo-` and then 7 characters with 1 or more non-digit characters. If the input is this:

```
"foo-1234567\nfoo-1234A67\nfoo-123$5^7"
```

I want an array from `match` like this: `["foo-1234A67", "foo-123$5^7"]`.

Regexes I have tried:

```
/^foo-\D+$/gmi   //nada
/^foo-(\D){1,7}$/gmi    //not even close
/^foo-\d*\D+\d*$/gmi    //good but matches > or < 7 characters
/^foo-(?=^foo-\d*\D+\d*$)(?=PR-.{7})/gmi    //empty string or null
```

<s>As always, this is code-golf, so shortest code wins.</s>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex to match individual valid values is simple: `/^foo-\d{7}$/`. So I'd suggesting `.split()`ing on the newlines and then `.filter()`ing to throw away values that don't match that regex:

```js
let getInvalid = input => input.split("\n").filter(v => !/^foo-\d{7}$/.test(v))

// following has all valid, so outputs empty array:
console.log( getInvalid("foo-1234567\nfoo-7654321\nfoo-1324536") )
// following has some invalid, so outputs them:
console.log( getInvalid("foo-1234567\nfoo-1234A67\nxyz-1234567\nfoo-123$5^7") )
// also works when there is only one value:
console.log( getInvalid("foo-1234567") )
// following has some invalid, so outputs them:
console.log( getInvalid("foo-123$5^7") )
```

**EDIT:** After Spencer's prompting I've realised the question asked to only match invalid values that start with `"foo-"` and are the right length. I.e., `"foo-123$5^7"` would be in the desired output, but `"foo-123"` and `"xyz-1234567"` would not be in the output even though they're invalid values. If that's the case you can use a regex with a negative lookahead to exclude values with 7 digits:

```
/^foo-(?!\d{7}).{7}$/
```

In context:

```js
let getInvalid = input => input.match(/^foo-(?!\d{7}).{7}$/gmi)

console.log( getInvalid("foo-1234567\nfoo-1234A67\nfoo-123") )
console.log( getInvalid("foo-1234567\nfoo-11111117\nfoo-1239999") )
console.log( getInvalid("foo-12##567\nxyz-1234A67\nfoo-123$5^7") )
```

Comment: That regex is wrong, the regex won't be that simple as the OP wants: *"I want match to give me each identifier which has foo- and then 7 characters with 1 or more non-digit characters. "*.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - I think my edit covers that requirement, and without the `.split().filter()`, but I've left my original answer too to allow for cases where *all* invalid values should be in the output and not just invalid values that match a specific format.

Comment: Yep looks good. Forcing it to not match 7 digits fulfills OP's requirement. Unfortunately I found that out a bit late :P

Comment: To clarify, I was indeed looking for your second answer (so I could avoid `split`ting and `filter`ing). Clever!

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the slickest solution, but you can do some good o'l fashion brute force position check for the non-digit character:

```
/^foo\-(\D......|.\D.....|..\D....|...\D...|....\D..|.....\D.|......\D)$/gm
```

Will give an update if I figure out a better way to check for the *"1 or more non-digit"* requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if `\n` is always expected, otherwise it might capture N + 12 characters per invalid identifier, where N is the number of non-digit characters.

`/foo-\d{0,6}\D+\d{0,6}/g`

Comment: It is not going to work for the one with 2 non numbers